# Python - how to pars this nested xml file?

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing, xmltodict

I am trying to parse this nested xml file into a data frame.
Here is the sample of xml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<response xmlns="http://www...">
  <sensor-time timezone="America/New_York">2020-08-10T12:19:26-04:00</sensor-time>
  <status>
    <code>OK</code>
  </status>
  <content>
    <elements>
      <element>
        <element-id>0</element-id>
        <element-name>Line 0</element-name>
        <sensor-type>SINGLE_SENSOR</sensor-type>
        <data-type>LINE</data-type>
        <from>2020-08-10T10:00:00-04:00</from>
        <to>2020-08-10T12:00:00-04:00</to>
        <resolution>FIVE_MINUTES</resolution>
        <measurements>
          <measurement>
            <from>2020-08-10T10:00:00-04:00</from>
            <to>2020-08-10T10:05:00-04:00</to>
            <values>
              <value label="fw">0</value>
              <value label="bw">0</value>
            </values>
          </measurement>
          <measurement>
            <from>2020-08-10T10:05:00-04:00</from>
            <to>2020-08-10T10:10:00-04:00</to>
            <values>
              <value label="fw">0</value>
              <value label="bw">0</value>
            </values>
          </measurement>
          <measurement>
            <from>2020-08-10T10:10:00-04:00</from>
            <to>2020-08-10T10:15:00-04:00</to>
            <values>
              <value label="fw">0</value>
              <value label="bw">0</value>
            </values>
          </measurement>
          <measurement>
      </element>
      <element>
        <element-id>1</element-id>
        <element-name>GP Test CL.01</element-name>
        <sensor-type>SINGLE_SENSOR</sensor-type>
        <data-type>LINE</data-type>
        <from>2020-08-10T10:00:00-04:00</from>
        <to>2020-08-10T12:00:00-04:00</to>
        <resolution>FIVE_MINUTES</resolution>
        <measurements>
          <measurement>
            <from>2020-08-10T10:00:00-04:00</from>
            <to>2020-08-10T10:05:00-04:00</to>
            <values>
              <value label="fw">0</value>
              <value label="bw">0</value>
            </values>
          </measurement>
          <measurement>
            <from>2020-08-10T10:05:00-04:00</from>
            <to>2020-08-10T10:10:00-04:00</to>
            <values>
              <value label="fw">0</value>
              <value label="bw">0</value>
            </values>
          </measurement>
          <measurement>
            <from>2020-08-10T10:10:00-04:00</from>
            <to>2020-08-10T10:15:00-04:00</to>
            <values>
              <value label="fw">0</value>
              <value label="bw">0</value>
            </values>
          </measurement>
          <measurement>
      </element>
    </elements>
  </content>
  <sensor-info>
    <serial-number>D1:82:34:5Z:3Q:3D</serial-number>
    <ip-address>000.000.00.0</ip-address>
    <name>Demo</name>
    <group>Test Devices</group>
    <device-type>PC2</device-type>
  </sensor-info>
</response>
```

I tried to use xmltodict librarry and I get to extract the individual emelements however since it is nested and has multiple elements and measurments within xml when i try to loop through it i am unable to get it work. Here is the code i have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import xmltodict
# Look for all xml files in directory
result = []
for file in glob.glob('*.xml'):
    with open(file) as fd:
        # Load each xml file and append it
        doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
        for element in doc['response']['content']['elements']['element']:
            for m in element['measurements']:
                data = {}
                for val in m['value']:
                    data['SERIAL_NUMBER'] = doc['response']['sensor-info']['serial-number']
                    data['IP'] = doc['response']['sensor-info']['ip-address']
                    data['name'] = doc['response']['sensor-info']['name']
                    data['Group'] = doc['response']['sensor-info']['group']
                    data['Device Type'] = doc['response']['sensor-info']['device-type']
                    data['element-id'] = element['element-id']
                    data['Line name'] = element['element-name']
                    data['From time'] = m['from']
                    data['to time'] = m['to']
                    data[val['label']] = val['value']
                result.append(data)
                df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

The error I am getting is: "TypeError: string indices must be integers" at the beginning of the look for m in element.

Ultimately what I am trying to get is output in this format:

[image]

Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score -1):

To get you at least close to where I believe you are trying to go, I would do something along these lines (and, obviously, you can modify it as you see fit):

```
rows = []
for element in doc.xpath('//elements//element'):
    row = []
    row.extend([(doc.xpath('//sensor-info/ip-address/text()')[0]),
    (doc.xpath('//sensor-info/name/text()')[0]),
    (doc.xpath('//sensor-info/device-type/text()')[0]),
    (doc.xpath('//sensor-info/group/text()')[0]),
    (element.xpath('.//element-id/text()')[0]),
    (element.xpath('.//element-name/text()')[0]),
    (measurement.xpath('//to/text()')[0]),
    (measurement.xpath('//from/text()')[0]),
    (measurement.xpath('//values[1]/value[@label="fw"]/text()')[0]),
    (measurement.xpath('//values[1]/value[@label="bw"]/text()')[0])])
    rows.append(row)
pd.DataFrame(rows, columns = cols)
```

Output (based on the sample xml in the question):

```
ip  sensor name     device  group   elem id     elem name   to  from    fw  bw
0   000.000.00.0    Demo    PC2     Test Devices    0   Line 0  2020-08-10T12:00:00-04:00   2020-08-10T10:00:00-04:00   0   0
1   000.000.00.0    Demo    PC2     Test Devices    1   GP Test CL.01   2020-08-10T12:00:00-04:00   2020-08-10T10:00:00-04:00   0   0
```

Comment: Yeah so i can get it like that with the method I am working on but when I put things in a nested loop that's where things get complicated.

Comment: @Slavisha84 I'm not sure what you mean.